# I want to call my function from another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a scrollView and there is a textView inside it and there is a function that slide my scrollView(with animation) in my main vc also I have a button(inside the black circle) ,when I press it, my pop up viewcontroller opens then I choose a value for animation delay in my function.
When I press my play button (inside the red circle) , I want to dismiss my pop up vc and I want my function to run. See:

```
func startScrollSlideShow(sliderValue: Float) {
    
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)){
        //reach bottom
        
        UIScrollView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(sliderValue), delay: 0.5, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
            self.scrollView.contentOffset.y += 3.5
        }) { (completion) in
            
            self.startScrollSlideShow(sliderValue: Float(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "sliderValue")!)!)
        }
    } else {           
        return
    }        
}

@objc func scrollTextView(){
    
    self.present(SliderViewController(title: "Otomatik Kaydırma"), animated: true, completion: nil)
    
//    self.startScrollSlideShow(sliderValue: Float(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "sliderValue")!)!)
}
```

these are in my main vc not my pop up vc.

Comment: You can do this by using protocols if you wanna call your function from another view controller

Comment: okey how can I use it

Comment: The pop up you created is another VC ??

Comment: Yeap bro but I solved my problem thank you

Comment: you can answer on your own question so other can finds it helpful ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the delegate pattern for this:

```swift
protocol PlayViewDelegate: class {
    func playButtonPressed()
}

// Implement the protocol in your Main VC
extension MainViewController: PlayViewDelegate {
    func playButtonPressed() {
        // Play
    }
}

// Add delegate to the alert like VC
class PlayViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: PlayViewDelegate?
    
    @IBAction
    func playPressed() {
        self.delegate?.playButtonPressed()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```